# Show that a mapping is not a scalar product.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $p := p_2x^2+p_1x+p_0$ and $q:= q_2x^2+q_1x+p_0$, show that the following mapping is not a scalar product of $\mathbb{R_{\leq 2}[x]}$.

$$< \cdot \ , \ \cdot>_1 \ : \ \mathbb{R_{\leq 2}[x]} \ \times \ \mathbb{R_{\leq 2}[x]} \to \mathbb{R}; <p,q>_1 =3p_2q_2 - 3p_1q_1 + p_0q_1 + p_1q_0 - 2p_0q_0$$

One of the properties of scalar products is that it's always positively definied, unless $p=q=0$ and then $<p,p>=0$. So I chose $p = 1$ and got $<1,1>_1=-2 < 0$. Since the mapping doesn't fulfill this criteria, it's not a scalar product of $\mathbb{R_{\leq 2}[x]}$.

I'm $99\%$ sure that I have the right answer but I'm not sure if I should describe my working out in more detail or use more information.

Comment: We get $\langle 1,1\rangle =2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The scalar product can be represented as $\left<p,q\right>_M = p_iM_{i,j}q_j$ with $M$ positive definite. Here

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & -3 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and $M$ has characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda) = (3-\lambda)(\lambda^2+\lambda-7)$